# Splitting timesheet data by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to group some data based on the date, then add that data together and spit it out into a rails database or table by said date in decimal form.

E.G. I want to take this

```
8 hrs, 38 mins 6:51am 3:30pm Apr 18
3 hrs, 44 mins 11:47am 3:32pm Apr 17
4 hrs, 23 mins 6:58am 11:20am Apr 17
```

and return

```
8.51 Apr 18
8.12 Apr 17
```

and so on.

Splitting the data apart should be easy using .to_string.split() but I'm not sure how to group it.  Ideally somebody could copy their entire clock-in for a month and have it return.

Comment: What have u tried so far?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far. That way we can help fix your code, not write something from scratch that is completely unassociated.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that thus:

```
a = ["8 hrs, 38 mins 6:51am 3:30pm Apr 18",
     "3 hrs, 44 mins 11:47am 3:32pm Apr 17",
     "4 hrs, 23 mins 6:58am 11:20am Apr 17"]

R = /
    (\d+)    # capture first group of digits
    \shrs,\s # match ' hrs, '
    (\d+)    # capture second group of digits
    \smins\s # match ' mins '
    \S+\s    # match any number of non-ws chars followed by one ws char
    \S+\s    # repeat
    (.+)     # capture remaining text
    /x    

a.map do |s|
  h,m,d = s.scan(R).first
  "#{(h.to_f+(m.to_f/60)).round(2)} #{d}"
end
  #=> ["8.63 Apr 18", "3.73 Apr 17", "4.38 Apr 17"]
```

For:

```
s = "8 hrs, 38 mins 6:51am 3:30pm Apr 18"
```

the steps are as follows:

```
b = s.scan(R)
  #=> [["8", "38", "Apr 18"]] 
h,m,d = b.first
  #=> = ["8", "38", "Apr 18"]
h #=> "8"
m #=> "38"
d #=> "Apr 18" 
c = h.to_f+(m.to_f/60)
  #=> 8.0 + (38.0/60)
  #=> 8.633333333333333 
e = c.round(2)
  #=> 8.63 
"#{e} #{d}"
  #=> "8.63 Apr 18"
```